Hölder? How to finish? General Case of IMO 2001 P2
Suppose $(a)_1^n$ are positive reals. Prove
$$\sum_{cyc}{\dfrac{a_1}{\sqrt[n-1]{a_1^{n-1}+\left(n^{n-1}-1\right)a_2a_3\cdots a_n}}}\geq 1$$
always holds.
What I've tried:
I tried using Hölder, and got a nice thing. I should find that paper i wrote on it. Then tried to finish it with AM-GM and Bernoulli. Any help is appreciated. On the other hand, notice that this is a generalization of IMO 2001 P.2. Any help is appreciated.
The following Hölder seems to be useful:
$$\left(\sum_{cyc}{\dfrac{a_1}{\sqrt[n-1]{a_1^{n-1}+(n^{n-1}-1)a_2a_3\cdots a_n}}}\right)^{n-1}\left(\sum_{cyc}{a_1\left(a_1^{n-1}+(n^{n-1}-1)a_2a_3\cdots a_n\right)}\right)\geq \left(\sum_{cyc}{a_1}\right)^n$$
Thus, we are left to prove
$$\left(\sum_{cyc}{a_1}\right)^n\geq \left(\sum_{cyc}{a_1\left(a_1^{n-1}+(n^{n-1}-1)a_2a_3\cdots a_n\right)}\right)$$
which seems easy with AM-GM but I coulnd't really end it up.

If you're asking how to finish, then you should be explicit on how you started. FWIW Modifying the existing Holders inequality should lead to an almost immediate solution, so please elaborate on what help you need (EG Do you not know of the existing Holder's solution?).

I've tried the following Hölder

$$\left(\sum_{cyc}{\dfrac{a_1}{\sqrt[n-1]{a_1^{n-1}+(n^{n-1}-1)a_2a_3\cdots a_n}}}\right)^{n-1}\left(\sum_{cyc}{a_1\left(a_1^{n-1}+(n^{n-1}-1)a_2a_3\cdots a_n\right)}\right)\geq \left(\sum_{cyc}{a_1}\right)^n$$

What remains is AM-GM:
$$\left(\sum_k a_k\right)^n = \sum_ka_k^n + \sum_{i_1,\dots i_n\in I}\prod_{j=1}^na_{j}^{i_j}$$
where $$I = \left\{(i_1,\dots, i_n)\vert\, 0\leq i_j <n, \, \sum_{j=1}^n i_j=n \ \right\}.$$
There are $n^n-n$ such monomials and when we do AM-GM on all of them, each $a_i$ will have the same exponent $e$ due to symmetry. But each monomial is homogeneous of degree $n$ and so it follows that $e=1.$ Therefore,
$$\left(\sum_k a_k\right)^n = \sum_ka_k^n + \sum_{i_1,\dots i_n\in I}\prod_ja_{i_j}\geq \sum_ka_k^n+(n^n-n)a_1a_2\dots a_n=\sum_{\text{cyc}}\left(a_1(a_1^{n-1}+(n^{n-1}-1)a_2a_3\dots a_n)\right)$$

Thanks. It seems easy with AM-GM but hard to express it. On the other hand, equality holds of course when $a_1=a_2=\cdots=a_n$. As I also mentioned in my first post, this generalization is my own work and $n=3$ gives IMO 2001 Problem 2 actually.

I think your indexing set condition is incorrect? It should be $ \sum i_s = n$ instead? EG For $n = 4$, we have terms like $a_1 a_2a_3^2$.

yeah you are right @CalvinLin

Alternative solution.
Remark. When $n=3$, this is the idea in the official solution ((1) can be proved by AM-GM). But for general $n$, it is not so nice (I don't know how to prove (1) by AM-GM).
Let $r := \frac{n}{n-1}(1 - n^{1-n})$. It suffices to prove that
$$\dfrac{a_1}{\sqrt[n-1]{a_1^{n-1}+\left(n^{n-1}-1\right)a_2a_3\cdots a_n}} \ge \frac{a_1^r}{a_1^r + a_2^r + \cdots + a_n^r}. \tag{1}$$
Since (1) is homogeneous, assume that $a_1 = 1$.
Let $x := a_2a_3 \cdots a_n$. By AM-GM, it suffices to prove that
$$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt[n-1]{1+\left(n^{n-1}-1\right)x}} \ge \frac{1}{1 + (n-1) x^{r/(n-1)}}, $$
or
$$f(x) := \left(1 + (n-1) x^{r/(n-1)}\right)^{n-1} - 1 - \left(n^{n-1}-1\right)x \ge 0. \tag{2}$$
We can prove that $f(x)$ is concave on $[0, c]$, and convex on $[c, \infty)$ for some $c\in (0, 1)$. Also, $f(0) = 0, f(1) = 0, f'(1) = 0$.
Thus, we have, for all $0 \le x \le c$,
$$f(x) \ge \min(f(0), f(c)),$$
and for all $x \ge c$,
$$f(x) \ge f(1) = 0.$$
Thus, $f(x) \ge 0$ on $x \ge 0$.
